# pager taglib not renaming exported url variables as documented

Tags: java, pagination, jstl

I'm using this [pager taglib solution](http://jsptags.com/tags/navigation/pager/index.jsp.html), it generates the links to the pages *almost* as instructed. It offers a way to customize the variable names that are used to iterate over the data set, and that's precisely what is causing problems.

This is how I've got set up so far

```
<pg:pager url="/search" 
items="1000" 
maxPageItems="10"
export="from=offset,currentPageNumber=pageNumber"
scope="request">
<pg:param name="w" value="${w}"/>
<pg:param name="e" value="${e}"/>

<pg:first unless="current"><a href="${pageUrl}"> &lt;&lt; first</a>&nbsp;</pg:first>
<pg:prev><a href="${pageUrl}"> &lt; prev</a>&nbsp;</pg:prev>    
<pg:pages>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${pageNumber == currentPageNumber}">
            ${pageNumber}
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <a href="${pageUrl}">${pageNumber}</a>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
&nbsp;</pg:pages>
<pg:next><a href="${pageUrl}">next &gt;</a>&nbsp;</pg:next>
<pg:last unless="current"><a href="${pageUrl}">last &gt;&gt;</a></pg:last>
</pg:pager>
```

Note, that based on the [documentation](http://jsptags.com/tags/navigation/pager/pager-taglib-2.0.html#export) you can control the name of the exported variables

> The export expression export="versatz=offset" would cause the
>   pageOffset variable to be available as <%= versatz %>

As you can see I'm trying to rename too the **offset** to **from** (This is what the backend is expecting)

```
export="from=offset,currentPageNumber=pageNumber"
```

But all the generated links are in the form (**Note the pager.offset=[number]**)

```
http://localhost:8080/search?w=param1&e=param2&pager.offset=10
```

What's that, that I'm doing wrong?
Anybody has experimented with this taglib?

Any feedback is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a bit late, but I encountered this same issue using the pager taglib mentioned above to support multiple unique pagers on a single page. Hope someone finds this useful...

It seems this parameter name is baked into the pager tag source code:

```
static final String OFFSET_PARAM = ".offset";
```

However, there is an `id` tag attribute whose value gets prefixed to the `OFFSET_PARAM` constant above during tag rendering. Its default value is `pager`:

```
static final String DEFAULT_ID = "pager";
```

These two values get concatenated to form an `idOffsetParam` field which is the final parameter name used internally by the pager tag:

```
private String idOffsetParam = DEFAULT_ID+OFFSET_PARAM;
```

**Solution**: If you specify your own `id` value in the tag declaration, you'll have partial control over the rendered parameter name:

```
<pg:pager 
    id="stackoverflow" 
    url="/search" 
    items="1000"
    ...
    ..
    .
```

This will make navigational links render as `?stackoverflow.offset=10`. The `.offset` portion of the param will remain, but at least you'll have some flexibility as to the uniqueness of the parameter name.